# Нет перевода на кнопке добавление ссылки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, ссылки, редактор

Отсутствует перевод кнопки "Add link" при добавлении ссылки к сообщению. На испанском SO переведено, но я почему-то не нашёл строки в Transifex. Может плохо искал.

> [image: add link]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В трансе ключ: `32210b37e4d23029d6ee2f5149e9c3e1`. Добавил перевод:

> Добавить ссылку

Comment: Утвердил перевод